# Name of the optimization model based on variable type

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, terminology, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

If the variable is binary 1,0  the model name is a binary integer optimization model
If the variable is any integer, the model name is integer optimization model
What if the variable is any integer that belongs to a set of values (ex, x belongs to {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5...an})?
What would be the name of this model?
Do you think "discrete optimizing model" is the correct name?
or is it still an integer optimization model (however, the integers are restricted to a set of given values)?

Answer (score 3):

You could call it *discrete optimization*, as in the tag I just added to your question.  Such restrictions can be modeled with binary variables, as shown in https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/how-to-linearize-membership-in-a-finite-set.